# For Loop to iterate over JSON objects inside an Array

Tags: java, android, json, for-loop, retrofit

How do I `get and show` each and every `JSON's Object's value` those I have inside an `Array` called `learning`

Here is how `JSON` Array looks like:

```
"learning": [
 {
  "code":"2K14 - 2",
  "os":"Windows - 2"
 },
 {
  "code":"2K15 - 2",
  "os":"Linux - 2"
 },
 {
  "code":"2K16 - 2",
  "os":"Mac - 2"
 }
]
```

**Code**

```
List<Learning> learning = value.getLearning();
for(Learning m : learning) {
     // I guess, here I am missing something, which is really useful
     String code = m.getCode();
     String os = m.getOs();
     viewHolder.learning.setText("Code: "+code+" OS: "+os);
}
```

When I `execute` my program, `getting` this:

```
Code: 2k16, OS: Mac - 2
```

Whereas I `want to get` something like `this`:

```
Code: 2k14 OS: Windows - 2,  Code: 2k15 OS: Linux - 2, Code: 2k16 OS: Mac - 2
```

Comment: how are you parsing the json ?

Comment: `viewholder`, im assuiming you are using the Viewholder pattern within a list adapter. No need for loop. GetView runs multiple times to render the list items.
It should display an item based on position.
Look into `getItem(position)`.

Comment: using Retrofit @Blackbelt

Comment: `viewHolder.learning.setText("Code: "+code+" OS: "+os);` is replacing the text. You need something along the lines of `viewHolder.learning.setText( viewHolder.learning.getText() + "Code: "+code+" OS: "+os);` or `viewHolder.learning.appendText(" Code: "+code+" OS: "+os);`. Not sure what methods are available to you, but that's the problem ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as, if want to show all data in single `TextView`:

```
viewHolder.learning.append("Code: "+code+" OS: "+os + ", ");
```

Use `TextView.append` instead of `TextView.setText`

Comment: thanks append() worked for me, I ticked your answer as useful and will accept in 7 mins, may I know How can I show comma between objects as shown above

Comment: please have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355559/populate-data-into-recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your Retrofit interface and all the model classes related to that?

and then you will have something like this to read it.

```
String text = "";
List<Learning> learning = value.getLearning();
for(Learning m : learning) {
     // I guess, here I am missing something, which is really useful
     String code = m.getCode();
     String os = m.getOs();
     text = text + "Code: " + code + " OS: " + os + ", ";
}
viewHolder.learning.setText(text);
```

Comment: thank you so much, I ticked your answer as useful, but @ρяσѕρєяK answered first, therefore I'll accept his solution :)

Comment: please have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355559/populate-data-into-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("learning");

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject obj  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String code = obj.getString("code");
    String os = obj.getString("os");

    Log.i("MyClass", "Code -> " + code);
    Log.i("MyClass", OS -> " + os);

}
```