# Populate Data into RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, android-recyclerview

I would like to show JSON Object's **data** into `RecyclerView` for that I have tried this but did not get any data.

May, I know where I am doing `mistake` and What I have `missed` ?

How could I pass `learning` objects data from `MainAdapter` to `LearningActivity`

**MainAdapter** class:

```
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        final Value value = values.get(i);

        ........

        List<Learning> learning = value.getLearning();

        viewHolder.btnCallNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LearningActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

**LearningActivity** class:

```
public class LearningActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       ......

        mAdapter = new LearningAdapter(valueList, R.layout.card_learning, getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: then why not populate valuelist

Comment: @VivekMishra can you point out the mistake ? please post your answer

Comment: already pointed out valueList=null. You have not initialised your list with any data

Comment: not getting.... what i have missed and I am already using:         mAdapter = new LearningAdapter(valueList, R.layout.card_learning, getApplicationContext()); @VivekMishra

Comment: just write `List<Learning> valueList = new ArrayList<Learning>();` and add some data in that list

Comment: check my update above, but yet not able to see data into RecyclerView

Comment: @Oreo: where you are adding data in `valueList ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have `resolved` my own issue.

I found a very **simple and straight** solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28173876/4675078)

Glad! worked for me

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("mylist", learning);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Answer (score -1):

**about setting your data**

```
private List<Learning> valueList = new ArrayList<Learning>();
```

This is new, empty ArrayList. You should fill it if you didn't already do it.
To test you implementation, you could add 2 empty objects:

```
valueList.add(new Learning());
valueList.add(new Learning());
```

At least, the recyclerview now should contain 2 empty items.

> Your data looks a bit strange, too:
>
> You set a List named value, a List of `Learning` objects.
>   In your adapter's `onBindViewHolder` function you have the following statement:
>
> ```
> final Value value = values.get(i);
> String stringLearning = "";
> List<Learning> learning = value.getLearning();
> ```
>
> This doesn't match your data. `Value value = values.get(i);` should return a > `Learning` object, not a list of `Learning` objects.

//Edit: Gnarf, you posted a whole new adapter while editing your question. Please ignore my above quoted text and next time think about what code you post before you ask ...

**your adapter class**

In your Adapter class, you need to implement `getItemCount()`. Because this method is abstract I assume you've already done it:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemCount%28%29

```
public abstract getItemCount () {
    return values.size();
}
```